# Old anime where the characters are beast/human characters

Tags: story-identification, anime

It's an old anime series where all the characters are a mix of human and animals. The main character is some species related to a dog and he has 3 other friends. The team has 4 people as i remembered, 2 guys and 2 girls. One of his friend is from a bird tribe. They were on an adventure to find something. I remembered they also could use some abilities. I last saw it on 2015. I don't remember the plot but i remembered some scenes.

The scenes i remembered was:

1. They were drowning
2. They fought a giant robot thing
3. The main character got mad when he
   is said to be related to a dog
   tribe

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example, what were their names? What were they wearing? What adventures did they have? What did the robot look like? Was the robot self-aware or controlled by someone else? Why would he get mad if he's a dog? What abliities did they have? What was the setting? Was this aimed at adults (with nudity/gore/violence) or kids? What was the animation style? You've said anime, but do you mean cartoon? What language was it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [*K.O. Beast*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K.O._Beast) (AKA *K.O. Century Beast Warriors*)

> The [1992] series is set in the distant future in which the Earth is split in two. The Southern Hemisphere is placed in another dimension, while the inhabitants of the Northern Hemisphere are able to morph into beast-like humanoids. Eventually the humans of the Southern Hemisphere, led by Uranus, attack the Beasts.
>
> The Three Beasts, Wan Derbard (Wan Dabadadatta) of the Tiger Tribe, Bud Mint (Baado Mint) of the Bird Tribe, and Mei Mer (Mei Mah) of the Mermaid Tribe, are taken prisoner along with Mei Mer's companion Tuttle Millen (Mekka Mannen, also of the Mermaid tribe), but manage to escape thanks to a little girl named Yuuni Charm Password. Together they seek Gaia, which they believe to be a fabulous treasure, but they are pursued by Uranus's minions: V-Darn the vicious mage-knight, V-Sion the warrior woman and Akumako, V-Darn's sadistic imp-like partner.
>
> [image]